# How to determine when a noun is an objective genitive versus a subjective genitive?

Tags: possessives, objective-case, of-genitive

St. Augustine writes in [*Soliloq.* i, 10](http://www.augustinus.it/latino/soliloqui/soliloqui_1_testo.htm#SO_001_010_017), as quoted in the English translation of St. Thomas Aquinas's [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 151 a. 3](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS151.html#SSQ151A3THEP1) ad 2:

> I consider that nothing so casts down the manly mind from its heights as the fondling **of women**, and those bodily contacts which belong to the married state.

Is the genitive "of women" here being used subjectively or objectively? Viz., are the women fondling (subjective genitive), or is St. Augustine referring to men's fondling women (objective genitive)? How do we know?

<sup>English version of [this Latin StackExchange question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/18870/576)</sup>

Comment: Preliminary point: "Of women" is not genitive. Genitive is an inflectional case of the noun marked by -'s (dog's) or by the apostrophe alone (dogs'). "The fondling of woman" is simply head+ _of_ complement.

Comment: The salient interpretation is that the women are being fondled by men, but if it was intended to mean that the women are doing the fondling then one might expect the prep "by", not "of".

Comment: As pointed out, English has no genitive case, or any cases at all. And there is no such thing as "subjective" versus "objective" use, in any case; that's an arbitrary judgement like "correct" and "incorrect", and not a grammatical property.

Comment: The fondling of women can be done by men or women.

Comment: @Davo Yes, else there wouldn't be any ambiguity here.

Answer (score 2):

We might be able to infer the meaning from context, but there is nothing in Augustine's sentence that would allow us to say with certainty whether the women were being fondled or doing the fondling.

By the way, this ambiguity is fairly common in English and does not require a gerund. For example: "I enjoyed the story of the old man." Was the story told by the old man, or was it about him?

Comment: Yes, the ambiguity is common. Is there a was to disambiguate it?

Comment: As I said, sometimes the context will permit only one reasonable interpretation. (E.g.: "I enjoyed the story of the universe's creation.") And some constructions allow only one interpretation. (E.g.: "I read that story of his.")

Answer (score -1):

One  thing is certain at the outset: it can't be  both. Suppose it  is subjective;  the objective possibility is then more or less considered as irrelevant. This means  that only the caresses from women would be detrimental; but then the author adds a complement of information: what also  matters is mere contact, which  must include some  fondling of some sort as performed by the man, the usual sort pertaining to the conjugal state, whatever precisely that sort is. Can we infer that  the married man's active part in the practice of fondling is  negligible compared to that of his partner? I don't think so, nor  would  certainly anyone else. Therefore, that marital sort of fondling, which is quite similar to that in non marital situations, would matter in the bringing about of this  possible demise from "the heights of the manly mind", but not  that in non marital contexts. This is very improbable, and one can  safely conjecture from the  linguistic context that what is meant is fondling as performed by the man.